# RPM packaging conflicting libraries

Tags: rpm, package-management, libraries

What is best practice for RPM packaging something that provides a library which in name shadows a system library?

*Background:*
For an RPM-backed Linux system, I am packaging a "self-contained" app `foo` that wants to live under /opt and supply as many of its own dependencies as it can, so as not to rely on the versions installed on the main system.  (`foo` uses LD_LIBRARY_PATH to avoid system libraries.)

Unfortunately, one of the `foo` dependencies is a library `grunk`, whose version is exactly that of the `libgrunk.so` required for the main system.  RPM's automatic *Provides:* generation then identifies two RPMs as providing this library.  (That's not really true — only the system package makes the library available to any program whatsoever, whereas the `foo` package makes it available only to `foo`.)

This confounds automatic dependency resolution sometimes.  For example, `yum` might install the wrong package or only one package when two are needed.

*Example:*

```
grunk-libs-1.2-3.$arch.rpm              # System Library
  Files:
    %{_libdir}/libgrunk.so.1
    %{_libdir}/libgrunk.so.1.2
  Provides:
    libgrunk.so.1()(%{_arch})

foo-x.y.z-r.$arch.rpm                   # App
   Files:
     /opt/foo
     /opt/foo/bin/...
   Requires:
     libgrunk.so.1()(%{_arch})          # foo needs grunk, but wants its own instance

foo-grunklibs-1.2-1.$arch.rpm           # App Dependency
  Files:
    /opt/foo/libs/libgrunk.so.1
    /opt/foo/libs/libgrunk.so.1.2
  Provides:
    libgrunk.so.1()(%{_arch})           # <-- same as from system "grunk-libs"
```

I've disabled AutoReqProv for now, but I want to be able to take advantage of RPM's automatic capabilities and dependency generation.  I want RPM to know that `foo.rpm` does require `foo-grunklibs.rpm` by virtue of the latter's `libgrunk.so.1`, but also know that the same library from the main system rpm won't suffice.

I think I'm at the limits of conventional use.  Is there a packaging technique I can use here to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

After considering this for a while, I think the more correct approach is to use RPM virtual resource "namespaces".  E.g.:

```
Provides:  resource               # 'resource' is available to the whole system
Provides:  namespace(resource)    # 'resource' is specifically available only to "namespace"
```

The RPMs end up looking like this:

```
grunk-libs.rpm
  Provides:  libgrunk.so.1()(%{_arch})       # System library.  unchanged

foo.rpm
  Requires:  /bin/sh
  Requires:  libc.so.6()(%{_arch})
  Requires:  foo(libgrunk.so.1()(%{_arch}))  # Note special foo(...) namespace

foo-grunklibs.rpm
  Provides:  foo(libgrunk.so.1()(%{_arch}))  # Note special foo(...) namespace
```

In this way the `foo` dependency on the special build of `libgrunk` cannot be satisfied by the ordinary `grunk-libs` RPM, but must be satisfied by the foo-specific build of that library.

My proof of concept looks like this:

```
Name:     foo
...
Source99: find-namespaced-requires     # Here's the magic

%define    _use_internal_dependency_generator 0
%define    __find_requires %{SOURCE99} foo /bin/sh glibc
```

Where the script *find-namespaced-requires* wraps the standard RPM *%{_rpmconfigdir}/find-requires* and filters its output.  It's first argument is the namespace (`"foo(...)"`) to use, and subsequent arguments are dependencies or RPMs providing dependencies which should *not* be namespaced.  In this example, I want `foo` to require the main system's /bin/sh and also the ordinary libc, libdl, libm, etc. from `glibc`, but every other dependency should be assumed to be specific to `foo`.

That could be made a little cleaner and more generic by wrapping up most of the above in a build-time RPM and saying something like:

```
Name:          foo
BuildRequires: special-deps-macros

%define _namespace            foo      # defaults to %{name} ?
%define _generic_dependencies ...      # defaults to /bin/sh glibc libselinux ?
```